# Ionic : Prevent alert auto dismiss when clicked on 'OK'

Tags: ionic-framework

Clicking on 'OK' automatically dismisses the alert. I want to add some logic inside 'OK' click handler and then decide if I want to dismiss the alert or not.

```
let inputsAlert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    ...
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'OK',
            handler: inputsData => {

                // Some logic here

                if (canDismiss) {
                    this.inputsAlert.dismiss();
                } else {
                    // Do nothing
                }
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> In the array of buttons, each button includes properties for its text, and optionally a handler. If a handler returns false then the alert will not automatically be dismissed when the button is clicked.

From https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/alert#buttons

Simply `return false` if you do not want the alert to be dismissed.

Comment: Works only when handler function is not declared as `async`.

Comment: @user1364368 Use ```thenables``` instead of ```async/await```.

Comment: @MayankKataria how to do that?

Comment: @user1364368 If from handler function call another function(Here all code) and this last declared as async, but the handler without async/await. it work! handler: (data) => {
                console.log(data);
                processFormPay(data);
                return false;
              },.... const processFormPay = async (data: any) => {//code here}